# Postgresql | Trying to create an materialized view for API endpoint

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, materialized-views

Good morning,
I would like your help with setting up a **materialized view** which must contain information such as the schema name, the table name, the type (**view, table, function, materialized view**) and the **endpoint** for the **API**. I've done this before but only for views, tables and functions. Now I aim to also integrate materialized views. But the task seems more complicated than expected...

Here is the code for the first version which does not include materialized views:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    -- Use of the COALESCE function which will return the first non-null value dans la liste
    COALESCE(t.table_catalog, r.routine_catalog) AS catalog,
    COALESCE(t.table_schema, r.routine_schema) AS schema,
    COALESCE(t.table_name, r.routine_name) AS name,
    COALESCE(t.table_type, r.routine_type) AS type,
    COALESCE(tp.grantee, rp.grantee) AS "user_name",
    COALESCE('/' || t.table_name, '/rpc/' || r.routine_name) AS endpoint
----------------------
--------joins---------
----------------------
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables) AS t
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines) AS r
    ON t.table_catalog = r.routine_catalog
        AND t.table_schema = r.routine_schema
        AND t.table_name = r.routine_name
    LEFT OUTER JOIN information_schema.table_privileges AS tp 
    ON t.table_catalog = tp.table_catalog 
        AND t.table_schema = tp.table_schema 
        AND t.table_name = tp.table_name 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN information_schema.routine_privileges AS rp 
    ON r.routine_catalog = rp.routine_catalog 
        AND r.routine_schema = rp.routine_schema 
        AND r.routine_name = rp.routine_name
----------------------
------CONDITIONS------
----------------------

WHERE 
    (
        -- Conditions for tables
        -- Add conditions if applicable
        t.table_schema != 'pg_catalog' 
        AND t.table_schema != 'information_schema' 
        AND t.table_schema != 'api_informations' 
        AND t.table_schema != 'public'
        AND t.table_schema != 'cron'
        AND tp.grantee != 'usersi_adm' 
        AND tp.grantee != 'organisationnel_adm'
    )
    OR (
        -- Conditions for functions
        -- Add conditions if applicable
        (
            r.routine_schema != 'pg_catalog'
            AND r.routine_schema != 'presentation'
            AND r.routine_schema != 'information_schema'
            AND r.routine_schema != 'api_informations'
            AND r.routine_schema != 'public'
            AND r.routine_schema != 'cron'
            AND rp.grantee != 'PUBLIC' 
            AND rp.grantee != 'usersi_adm'
                    
        )
    );
```

Then I tried that, it's pretty good but I don't get the permissions back.:

```
SELECT
    n.nspname AS schema_name,
    c.relname AS object_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN c.relkind = 'r' THEN 'BASE TABLE'
        WHEN c.relkind = 'v' THEN 'VIEW'
        WHEN c.relkind = 'm' THEN 'MATERIALIZED VIEW'
    END AS object_type,
    pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) AS owner,
    COALESCE('' || a.rolname, '') AS permissions,
    CASE 
        WHEN c.relkind IN ('v', 'm') THEN format('/%s/%s', n.nspname, c.relname)
        ELSE format('/%s', c.relname)
    END AS object_location
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_class c
JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
LEFT JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m ON m.roleid = c.relowner
LEFT JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_roles a ON m.member = a.oid
WHERE
    c.relkind IN ('r', 'v', 'm') AND
    n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%' AND
    n.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema','public','api_informations');
```

So I need help to set up a code that will also contain the materialized views. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: In the pg_class table you also have the column relacl that has information about the permissions. See also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS

Comment: Tip start `psql` with `-E`. This will show the query `psql` uses to return the information from a `\<meta-command>`. Then do `\dp <some_mat_view>`. Note form here [Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html): *If the “Access privileges” column is empty for a given object, it means the object has default privileges (that is, its privileges entry in the relevant system catalog is null). Default privileges always include all privileges for the owner, and can include some privileges for PUBLIC depending on the object type, as explained above.*